# Java development in docker container without local JDK?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

Is it possible to create a docker container that runs a local (`spring-boot`) java project, without having to install a JDK on the local development machine?

I mean: would I have to add the sourcecode directory to the container as mount, and build the app there?
Because, if I don't have a local JDK, I cannot build a final `app.jar` that I could share to the container.

My goal is to create a container that can be used for developtmend, without the developer requiring to install a local JDK.

Examples I could found have been like:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:11
RUN mkdir /opt/app
COPY japp.jar /opt/app
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/opt/app/japp.jar"]
```

Problem: this requires build of the application, which is only possible if JDK/JRE is installed locally.
But that's what I'm trying to prevent!

Comment: checkout docker multistage builds, they can do this.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. You need a docker container that has the JDK installed. Have you tried it? All IDEs require a JDK though, so development without it makes no sense.

Comment: @M.Deinum could you give an example link?

Comment: The [Docker Documenation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) has some explaining on this with a Go sample. There are several tutorials out there doing that for java with either Maven or Gradle.

Comment: @M.Deinum Please have a look at my update, I'm looking for a solution that does not require a prebuild app.jar to put into the container.

Comment: Yes, you can. Check out https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/ in the 'Multi-stage build' section.

Comment: A Docker container is designed to prevent you from accessing host files, it often requires administrator access to run, you'll probably need to install Docker, and your IDE might not be able to use the tools in the isolated container.  If you can work around all of these problems, it's probably possible.

Comment: @HansKilian but that requires to rebuild the app.jar each time for a code change. Is there no way just sharing the development directory with java code to the container, and just run the code inside the container thereafter?

Comment: @membersound I don't understand how you'd accomplish that. You always need to compile your program when you make changes, docker or no docker.

Comment: Look at the guide and the proper tutorials... Use a multistage build where in the first container you run the build, then copy the stuff from container 1 to container 2 to build the runtime container.

Answer (score 0):

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM maven:3-eclipse-temurin-11 as dependencies
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn -B dependency:go-offline

FROM dependencies as dev
COPY src src
ENTRYPOINT ["mvn", "spring-boot:run"]
```